# How to import/require a remote script at runtime without appending a node to the DOM

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to integrate with a service that only provides their library as a hosted script.

I only know the sever it will be hosted on at runtime (different servers host their own copy of the library with various config values built into that copy).

I cannot dynamically append a script tag to the DOM.

The script contents look like this:

```
FOO_LIBRARY=function(){...)()
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
const path = `https://${isTestMode ? 'test' : 'prod'}.server.com/script.js`;
const script = magicScriptFetcher(path);
script();
const client = new FOO_LIBRARY.client;
```

Comment: This might be one of the few cases where `eval` may be justified (assuming no CORS issues), but I'm not entirely sure